# gnu tree: downloading and installing on linux account with no root access?

Tags: installation, gnu, tree

I would like to download and install (compile) gnu tree on linux machine with no root access, but Googling GNU tree doesn't even give me a page where to download it to. Anyone?

Comment: No root access: just export an user directory such as `~/.local/bin`, etc to  `PATH`, then similarly `~/.local/lib` to `LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then use [GNU stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) to manage your locally built packages. Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the official website and the latest sources: http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/

Rather than compiling *tree* you may want to have a look at this one-liner in shellscript:

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

Not as clean as *tree* but good enough for the majority of cases !

For another implementation of tree in bash the guy made a good script here: http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/bash/btree

Comment: The problems with such one-liners are, as you have noted yourself, that 1) they are not as clean as *tree* and 2) they are only "good enough" for the "majority".

Comment: A machine without root access is "good enough" too for the majority, we are not talking about an edge case here but a specific one.  Moreover when you are down to compiling your tools on a machine you're not root on you may be interested in quicker solution as a bash script ; installing a compiler and resolving dependencies isn't that fun just to display a tree representation of some folders.